# Show download progress from Chaquopy Python to android java

Tags: android, chaquopy

I am downloading a file in python code which returns me progress of the file downloaded in percentage. Is there any way i can send back these percentage values back to android java code?

Assuming percentage values are returned from a callback function every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Chaquopy FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#faq-callback):

> There are many ways of doing this: here’s one example from the Electron Cash project:
>
> - Kotlin code [passes a method reference](https://github.com/Electron-Cash/Electron-Cash/blob/android-4.2.3-2/android/app/src/main/java/org/electroncash/electroncash3/Daemon.kt#L41) to Python.
> - The Python code creates a background thread which later [calls the method](https://github.com/Electron-Cash/Electron-Cash/blob/android-4.2.3-2/android/app/src/main/python/electroncash_gui/android/console.py#L235) using normal Python syntax.

Comment: What are the data types apart from string that we can pass from python to Kotlin?

Comment: @GirishGarg: See https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html#data-types.